# VirtualBox randomly resets VM's network

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtualbox

I have a VM which is running by VirtualBox 6.1. Ubuntu Server 18.04 is installed on hypervisor and Ubuntu Server 22.04 is installed on VM. The internet on VM works through "Host-Only Adapter" (yes, "Host-Only" for Internet). The uptime of VM now is 36 days and the uptime of hypervisor is 62 days, and during this time the hypervisor randomly reset network on VM two times already. I realized it when I saw "**e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Reset adapter**" on the virtual screen of VM. Also I can see this if I run `dmesg` on my VM.

The type of Host-Only is "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)". The promiscuous mode is disabled.

Is this a bug? Why hypervisor is doing this and is there a way to stop it?